# Rails reconnecting to db while inside a transaction

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, transactions, reconnect

When using the reconnect: true in database.yml, Rails will automatically reconnect to the database if the connection drops. However, Rails appears to be completely ignorant when the reconnect happens in the middle of a transaction, with the effect that the earlier portion of the transaction before the reconnect is automatically rolled back by the database when the connection drops, but all the queries generated by Rails after the reconnect are simply executed on the new connection - outside of any transaction! I would expect an exception to be raised in case the reconnect happens in the middle of a transaction, anyone knows of any patches/gems that do this?

Comment: You should investigate why the database connection is closed, and fix that. It does not happen "randomly"; there is always a reason.